# DD4T SiteEdit not allowing all fields to editable even though the site edit tags are provided

Tags: 2013, dd4t, siteedit

I am using the following code to render a set of links. I am however not able to edit the internal_link field through site edit. It is allowing only one field to be editable though I have provided site edit tags for all fields.

In this case...only title is editable.When I remove the site edit tag for title, the inter_link becomes editable.

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be very much appreciated:

```
@if (lnk.ContainsKey("internal_link"))  
        {
            if(lnk["type"].Value == "Open New Window")
                {  
                    var lk = lf.ResolveLink(lnk["internal_link"].LinkedComponentValues[0].Id);
                    if(lnk.ContainsKey("image"))
                    {
                    @Html.SiteEditField(Model.Component, lnk["internal_link"])
                     <a href="@baseurl@lk" target="_blank">         
                     @Html.SiteEditField(Model.Component, lnk["image"]) 
                     <img src="@lnk["image"].LinkedComponentValues[0].Multimedia.Url" alt="@lnk["image"].LinkedComponentValues[0].Title" />
                     @Html.SiteEditField(Model.Component, lnk["title"])
                     @Html.Raw(lnk["title"].Value)</a>
                    }

                }
            if(lnk["type"].Value == "Same Window") 
                {
                    var lk1 = lf.ResolveLink(lnk["internal_link"].LinkedComponentValues[0].Id);

                    if(lnk.ContainsKey("image")){
                    <p>
                    @Html.SiteEditField(Model.Component, lnk["internal_link"])
                    <a href="@baseurl@lk1">
                    @Html.SiteEditField(Model.Component, lnk["image"]) 
                    <img src="@lnk["image"].LinkedComponentValues[0].Multimedia.Url" alt="@lnk["image"].LinkedComponentValues[0].Title" />
                    @Html.SiteEditField(Model.Component, lnk["title"])
                    @Html.Raw(lnk["title"].Value)</a></p>
                    }

                    if(!lnk.ContainsKey("image")){                      
                    @Html.SiteEditField(Model.Component, lnk["internal_link"])
                    <a href="@baseurl@lk1">@Html.SiteEditField(Model.Component, lnk["title"])
                    @Html.Raw(lnk["title"].Value)</a>
                    }
                } 
        }
```

//UPDATED CODE:

```
@if (lnk.ContainsKey("internal_link"))  
        {
            if(lnk["type"].Value == "Open New Window")
                {  
                    var lk = lf.ResolveLink(lnk["internal_link"].LinkedComponentValues[0].Id);
                    if(lnk.ContainsKey("image"))
                    {
                    @Html.SiteEditField(Model.Component, lnk["internal_link"])
                     <a href="@baseurl@lk" target="_blank">         
                     <p>@Html.SiteEditField(Model.Component, lnk["image"]) 
                     <img src="@lnk["image"].LinkedComponentValues[0].Multimedia.Url" alt="@lnk["image"].LinkedComponentValues[0].Title" /></p>
                     <p>@Html.SiteEditField(Model.Component, lnk["title"])
                     @Html.Raw(lnk["title"].Value)</p></a>
                    }

                }
            if(lnk["type"].Value == "Same Window") 
                {
                    var lk1 = lf.ResolveLink(lnk["internal_link"].LinkedComponentValues[0].Id);

                    if(lnk.ContainsKey("image")){

                    @Html.SiteEditField(Model.Component, lnk["internal_link"])
                    <a href="@baseurl@lk1">
                    <p>@Html.SiteEditField(Model.Component, lnk["image"]) 
                    <img src="@lnk["image"].LinkedComponentValues[0].Multimedia.Url" alt="@lnk["image"].LinkedComponentValues[0].Title" /></p>
                    <p>@Html.SiteEditField(Model.Component, lnk["title"])
                    @Html.Raw(lnk["title"].Value)</p></a>
                    }

                    if(!lnk.ContainsKey("image")){

                    @Html.SiteEditField(Model.Component, lnk["internal_link"])
                    <a href="@baseurl@lk1"><p>@Html.SiteEditField(Model.Component, lnk["title"])
                    @Html.Raw(lnk["title"].Value)</p></a>
                    }
                } 
        }
```

Comment: This has now been resolved: updated the modified code above. I had to add<p> tags to each field items to make sure all site edit tags worked.

Comment: Doesn't need to be `<p>`, any element will work, even non-HTML (though that may mess up display)

Answer (score 4):

As you've already discovered, the Experience Manager comment tags need to be wrapped with some HTML element *per field* in order that the UI can display them correctly and allow editing.